# htaccess file not redirecting 404 pages to my index.php page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

this htaccess rule is not redirecting 404 errors or simply page not founds to the index page

what am I doing wrong?

my localhost url is generated by IIS so it comes out as: localhost:26139/

but even if I prefix that to my rewrite base it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS doesn't natively use .htaccess files.

In IIS  uses a file called Web.config  you need to work on that file for redirection

Ref Link : http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig